# CSS -moz-apperarence not working for radio buttons

Tags: html, css

I am styling some radio buttons but the style is not working for Mozilla Firefox

here is the css

```
input[type="radio"] {
                    -webkit-appearance:none;
                    -moz-appearance:none;
                    appearance:none;
                    display:inline-block;
                    width:25px;
                    height:25px;

                    cursor:pointer;
                    outline:none;
                    border:2px solid rgba(169,168,164,0.8);

                }

                input[type="radio"]:checked {
                    border:2px solid black;

                    outline:none;

                }
```

and here is the inputs
my radio button is:

`<input type="radio" id="color" name="color" value="<?php echo $col_id;?>" style="background-color:red" >
<input type="radio" id="color" name="color" value="<?php echo $col_id;?>" style="background-color:blue" >`

here is also the fiddle : 
http://jsfiddle.net/15eboqx8/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is highly recommended not to style radio buttons/checkboxes like this.

```
Non-standard
This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=605985

Have a look at using [a label to visually mimic field](http://codepen.io/mitchmc/pen/pebIx), so in essence you hide the radio button, style the label as if a radio button, then use the `:checked` pseudo selector to toggle the checked/unchecked states.

EDIT:
I have recreated your radio boxes using the method I described.

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/eyq8bkz6/